# Different capabilities for the same role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a project where I need to add "capabilities" based on a role. I explain.

My User can participate to Events. But each User has a different role on each Event. As well, two user with the same Role on an Event can have different "capabilities". Let says that one can update a resource, the other can't.

Do you know any Gem that can achieve that ?

-- Update --

My case :

What I meant is that is a have a Role 'Event Organizer', I want to be able to add different capabilities for this role. I want one 'Event Organizer' to be able to add `Shop` to an `Event`, but an other 'Event Organizer' can't do it.

Example:

You can take the example of a "Company" with door lock controlled by NFC key. You have a role "Visitor", some "Visitor" can open your secret laboratory, some just have access to your office. I don't wan't to create a "Role" for each door of my company.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain the [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9) gem which can do that, also Pundit and CanCanCan, and [many others here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization).

#### Updated

In [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9) to add different capabilities for different users:

```
user1.has_role! :updater, the_event
user2.has_role! :viewer, the_role
```

And then in your controller:

```
before_filter set_event

access_control do
  allow :viewer,  of: :event, to: %i[show index]
  allow :updater, of: :event, except: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Do you have any example on a to add different capabilities on the same Role ? I'm from CanCan, seems really tricky to me. I see that in acl9, I can define Role but not different capabilities for a Role.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by different capabilities for the same role, the capabilities (or permissions) are directly related to the role. If you want different permissions then you need to add a different role.

Comment: What I meant is that is a have a Role 'Event Organizer', I want to be able to add different capabilities for this role. I want one 'Event Organizer' to be able to add Shop to an Event, but an other 'Event Organizer' can't do it.

Comment: Well, in acl9 you can have a role just by itself, AND you can have a role on a class, AND you can have a role on a specific instance. So, if what you're saying is that you have two different events, and you only want the organizer of each event to be able to add Shop to their own event then yes, that's simple. If you want to have precisely the same role, on precisely the same object, for two different users and have them have different permissions then no, I don't understand why you'd want that and AFAIK you can't do that with any role based access control library.

Comment: Well, that's what my app require. You can take the example of a "Company" with door lock controlled by NFC key. You have a role "Visitor", some "Visitor" can open your secret laboratory, some just have access to your office. I don't wan't to create a "Role" for each door of my company.

Comment: But you're asking for a different response from the system even if both visitors are using the same keycode. In role-based access control systems, the role **is** the key that determines what permissions the user has. Users with the same roles have the same permissions. If you want individual users to have different permissions despite having the same role then you shouldn't use role-based access control, you should just do your own permission system based on the user id or whatever your key is for making that determination.

Comment: When you say things like "I want to add different capabilities", in a role-based system what that means is that you'll add another role. So, you might have two users who are "Event Organizers" but if you want different permissions then you wouldn't based the permissions on that role, instead you'd add **ANOTHER** role to one of them like `:event_admin` and then the permission to add a Shop to an Event would be based on **that** `:event_admin` role, not on the "Event Organizer" role (whatever that is in your system).

Comment: I need a "Role" to identify who is my user. A visitor ? A VIP ? A Security Guard ? So I need "role" to do that. Well, I think I need it, that's the purpose of my question. Maybe I just to add capabilities like boolean in my DB and the "Role" is finally just a string.

Comment: The roles we're talking about here are really what you use for assigning capabilities. If you want to have some other grouping of your users like VIP, Security Guard, or Event Organizer that don't map to permissions with your system then you can do that outside of the RBAC system you choose to use.