# Dynamic permissions rubygem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

Is there a framework or common pattern for implementing dynamic permissions?

Something like Rolify but where I wouldn't have to restart the server.

I guess I could just iterate through each User that has a role and add/remove permissions but that seems like overwork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reminds me a lot of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28618440/152786).

Your question is very difficult to understand because all the role-based access control gems like rolify allow the implementation of dynamic permissions.

So, I'm left wondering if, like the other question that I linked to above, perhaps you've misunderstood the way to use these role-based systems.

The idea is that you grant access/permissions to **roles** (not individual users) and then you assign users to as many different roles as they need in order to have the access/permissions that they need.  Obviously, you can assign users to roles dynamically, that's what these libraries provide.